# How to bind a keydown to border that has a Mousedown Event in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a border:

```
<Border x:Name="butborder1" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="0,10,10,0" 
 BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,98,33,0" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="87" IsEnabled="False" MouseUp="butborder1_MouseUp" 
 KeyDown="butborder1_KeyDown">
```

It has a MouseUp Event:

```
private void butborder1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
        butborder5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        rotate.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        butborder4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        image2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        butborder1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        image4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        butborder2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        image3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        butborder3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        image1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        SetInput(true);
        butin(false);
        butborder4.IsEnabled = true;}
```

I want to Bind a keydown Event to that, but it is not work:

```
private void butborder1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if (e.Key == Key.Insert)
    {
        butborder1_MouseUp(null,null);
    }
}
```

The Brief:

I have a Border That Act like a button on my WPF Form, It has a MouseUp Event that works perfect, My user wants to press a key instead of Click that button, So I should Give it a KeyDown Event... But KeyDown Event Can't Call the MouseUp Event!...

Comment: what does it mean - don't work, please clarify

Comment: My border Act like a button. I want to give it a shortcut key

Comment: When i press the Insert Button on my keyboard, the butborder1_MouseUp should be run!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad so try this. I think this should call the function
`butborder1_MouseUp(null,null);`

```
private void butborder1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    // This is not always true.
    //if (e.Key == Key.Insert)
    //{
        butborder1_MouseUp(null,null);
    //}
}
```

Comment: This function can't find the Insert key... When i press the Insert Button on my keyboard, the butborder1_MouseUp should be run!

Comment: What is your real problem? Bind a keydown Event or  find the Insert key ?

Comment: I have a Border That Act like a button on my WPF Form, It has a MouseUp Event that works perfect, My user wants to press a key instead of Click that button, So I should Give it a KeyDown Event... But KeyDown Event Can't Call the MouseUp Event!